# LaTeX Beamer Metropolis -- Patching Conflict Again

Tags: beamer, patching, beamer-metropolis

After a recent update to my installation of TeXLive 2016, I get

```
l.275 ...opolis}{Patching section title failed}\@ehc
```

when I try to xelatex or lualatex the file demo.tex in 
`texmf-dist/doc/latex/beamertheme-metropolis/demo.tex`

(The same happens with my own sources.)

I thank Joseph Wright and the maintainer of metropolis for having fixed the same problem early this year, in January. Unfortunately, it has crept back in.

Comment: TeX Live 2016 has been frozen several months ago and TeX Live 2017 has been released. What do you mean by “updating TeX Live 2016”?

Comment: I really hate it to have to wade through my tex system to retrieve a demo file only to test an issue. Is it so difficult to paste a minimal example in the question?

Comment: There is already an issue report: https://github.com/matze/mtheme/issues/303

Comment: https://github.com/matze/mtheme/issues/303

Comment: duplicate of this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404815/beamer-theme-metropolis-issue-on-macosx-high-sierra

Answer (score 3):

This behaviour is due to a bug in the `metropolis` theme which was fixed with v1.2 of the `metropolis` theme.

Where possible, you should [update your TeX
distribution](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437) to install the
current release. If this is not possible, for example if you want to
change only this one package or where you do not have the privileges
to update the entire distribution, you will need to [install the
package locally](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137).  This option should be considered a last resort, since for more complex packages there may be package dependencies that will make local installation more complicated and error-prone.

## Note:

In Debian `stretch` for instance you are stuck with TexLive2016, so you can simply update/install the beamertheme-metropolis package using `tlmgr`:
`tlmgr install beamertheme-metropolis`